# Storing Data in model for comparison in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I get a `expires_in` Int from my backend when I refresh my token.

I need to store the Date that the token will expire in, and check it before I make an API call.

So my model looks like this:

```swift
    struct TokenModel: Codable {
        var access_token: String
        var refresh_token: String
        var token_type: String
        var expires_in: Int
        var scope: String

        var expires: Date? {
            let now = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            return calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: expires_in, to: now)
        }
    }
```

and later check the `expires` against the current date.

What is worrying me is the calendar parameter. Could the user change the date/time on their device or the calendar and then the logic will not work?

I wanted to convert to `iso8601Formatter` but can't seem to convert easily to date...

Comment: Calendar changes are irrelevant because `Date` is an absolute point in time and independent of the current calendar. Date/time changes on the device can be detected by subscribing to the [`UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationsignificanttimechangenotification) notification. – But what timespans are we talking about? Can you simply start a timer which fires when the token has expired?

Comment: The token will be stored in the keychain so might expire when the App is closed. The time span is <2 days.

Comment: `applicationSignificantTimeChange:` in the app delegate is also called when your app is suspended and then comes into foreground again. – But is it worth the trouble? If the user sets the device time back then the next API will probably still fail if the token is expired, and you can request a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a defect here. `expires` doesn't return the the true expiration date. It always returns now + `expires_in` seconds. That date will always be in the future.

A possible way of fixing this is to mark the creation time of the instance.

```swift
struct TokenModel: Codable {
    var access_token: String
    var refresh_token: String
    var token_type: String
    var expires_in: Int
    var scope: String

    let startingDate = Date()
    var expires: Date? {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: expires_in, to: startingDate)
    }
}
```

This also has problems. Carelessly handling `TokenModel` instances might cause additional defects.

---

If the server provides the expiration time, then you can run into issues with time drift. If the server is a few seconds off or if the client is a few seconds off from standard time, then the expiration time is off.

---

The solution I've used a few times is to split the responsibilities. Create a separate authorization manager.

```swift
struct TokenModel: Codable {
    let access_token: String
    let refresh_token: String
    let token_type: String
    let expires_in: Int
    let scope: String
}

class AuthorizationManager {
    var accessToken: String?
    var refreshToken: String?
    var tokenType: String?
    var expiration: Date?
    var scope: String?

    lazy var calendar: Calendar = .current

    func update(token: TokenModel) {
        if let tokenExpiration = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: token.expires_in, to: Date()) {
            accessToken = token.access_token
            refreshToken = token.refresh_token
            tokenType = token.token_type
            expiration = tokenExpiration
            scope = token.scope
        }
    }
}
```